# Netbeans step through out of project tree files for debugging (PHP)

Tags: wordpress, debugging, netbeans, plugins, wamp

I am writing a Wordpress plugin that depends on another plugin with netbeans.
The project is just containing the files of my plugin and I want to keep it that way to have a clean git repository.

The problem:
I rely on another plugin and want to understand how that plugin works.  For this, I want to "step through" the other plugin.
I want to do this on my localhost configuration.

I have basically two destinations:

- The project is in my home directory in my github folder
- The server files are under c:\wamp64\www\wordpress ...., where the localhost is running
- The project is essentially set up correctly to copy files from my github directory to the localhost path (Properties -> Sources)

Then:

- I set an include path to the localhost -> wordpress folder in the project properties, and when I now search for a definition in my code that refers to the other plugin, the corresponding file is opened (did not work before setting the include path)
- Debugging essentially works, but when I step into a function of the other plugin, the bar becomes grey and the corresponding file is not opened.

Can I change some setting for netbeans to open up the other file (not in the project tree) and step through it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reasonable workaround.
I just created a new PHP project in Netbeans with existing sources.
As source, I used the entire wordpress installation in the wamp server path, i.e. c:\wamp64\www\wordpress

I can now 'debug' and step through this new project, but I also need to add the corresponding breakpoints in the files from the server path.
It requires some discipline as I have to open the files from my plugin twice, once in the server path and once in the project path, but only edit the files in the project path.

It works 'ok', but I would still be interested to hear if someone has a more proper solution to this.